# Is it possible to catch & edit swf loads in remote swf?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Since i'm having some issues with a sandbox here, i'm looking for a little workaround that should work to proxify the assets loaded by a remote swf.

Currently after loading a remote swf, and trying to draw a bitmap i get the following error:

```
Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: http://urlhere cannot access http://remotehost/clothes/bg/bg_10438411_bg.swf. This may be worked around by calling Security.allowDomain.
```

Now, i want to see if it's possible to catch & change the swf's that the remote swf loads. So i can load them through a php file and then into the swf instead. Basically editing the URL that it loads the swf from.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some code, it would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: something like this? http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-using-a-php-proxy-to-load-assets-into-flash/

Comment: Yes, however i have no actual access to the remote swf. So i still need to catch the requests being made and edit the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to draw a snapshot of a loaded swf using BitmapData.draw().
You will either need a crossdomain.xml on the server holding the swf you're loading, either proxy it through a server side script.

If you have a crossdomain.xml, you can use pass a LoaderContext as the second parameter of Loader's [load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load%28%29) method, explicitly requesting crossdomain checking. 
If the security requirements are not met, a [SecurityErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SecurityErrorEvent.html) will be dispatched.
Also, you should catch the [SecurityError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/SecurityError.html) thrown when calling BitmapData's draw() method and use the loaderInfo's url to change it and use it however you see fit:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityError);
loader.load(new URLRequest('yoursite.com/yourfile.swf'),new LoaderContext(true));

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{
    var clone:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1,1);//create a small bitmap to try and draw into
    try{//draw the contents
        clone.draw(event.target.content);
    }catch(error:SecurityError){//expect security error
        trace('SecurityError while loading',event.target.url,'details\n',error.message);    
    }
}
function securityError(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void{
    trace(event.target.url,event);
}
```

You can also add listeners for IOErrorEvent and HTTPStatusEvent, just in case anything goes wrong (file is missing, wrong url, etc.)